# OSMBonuspack Custom KML marker appearing in wrong color

Tags: android, kml, osmdroid

I've been trying to change the style of my KML so KmlPoint would be represented with a custom marker of my choice.

Here are the markers I'm using:

[image]

I successfully made the wanted points show up with the respective markers, but they look like a color filter might be applied to them or the bitmap is simply corrupted and I don't know why.
[image: Screenshot]

Here is my code:

```
KmlDocument dryKmlDocument = new KmlDocument();
    File f2 = new File(appPath + "/dry_hydrant.kml");
    dryKmlDocument.parseKMLFile(f2);
    Bitmap blueBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.blue, null)).getBitmap();
    Style dryStyle = new Style(blueBitmap, 0x901010AA, 1.0f, 0x20AA1010);
    ZoneStyler dryZoneStyler = new ZoneStyler(dryStyle, dryKmlDocument, osmView);
    dryKmlOverlay = (FolderOverlay)dryKmlDocument.mKmlRoot.buildOverlay(osmView, null, dryZoneStyler, dryKmlDocument);

    KmlDocument fireKmlDocument = new KmlDocument();
    File f3 = new File(appPath + "/fire_hydrant.kml");
    fireKmlDocument.parseKMLFile(f3);
    Bitmap redBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.red, null)).getBitmap();
    Style fireStyle = new Style(redBitmap, 0x00000000, 1.0f, 0x00000000);
    ZoneStyler fireZoneStyler = new ZoneStyler(fireStyle, fireKmlDocument, osmView);
    fireKmlOverlay = (FolderOverlay)fireKmlDocument.mKmlRoot.buildOverlay(osmView, null, fireZoneStyler, fireKmlDocument);
```

Can someone point me to what could be causing this?

EDIT: Imgur didn't want to show up my bmp marker images so I took a screenshot in windows explorer instead.

Comment: Use png format. And ensure the corners are fully transparent (you cannot do that with the Windows Paint, you need something like IcoFX, Gimp, PhotoShop,... ).

Comment: @MKer I used GIMP for transparency, I will try in the .png format next week and come back if it was the problem.

Comment: @MKer Yes you were right! The .bmp images were not supported. If you could change your comment for an answer it would be greatly appreciated and we could mark this question as answered.

Comment: You can "vote" for a comment if you want.

Comment: Sure, but I can't mark the question as answered from a comment. If you don't want to make an answer I'll just make a community wiki. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PNG format, and ensure the corners are fully transparent (you cannot do that with the Windows Paint, you need something like IcoFX, Gimp, PhotoShop,... ).